# To have nice tabbed text next to equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, subequations

I want

[image]

I have at the moment

[image]

by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{equation}
    \omega_c = \sqrt{\omega_{0}^{2} - \mu^{2}}, \mu < \omega_{0}, \text{ Underdamped}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
    \omega_c = \sqrt{\mu^{2} - \omega_{0}^{2}}, \mu > \omega_{0}, \text{ Overdamped}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
    \omega_c = 0, \mu > 0, \text{ Critically damped.}
  \end{equation}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

which I do not like.

**How can you have nicely tabbed text next to equations?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A regular `align` (from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) will do here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
  \omega_c &= \sqrt{\omega_{0}^{2} - \mu^{2}}, & \mu &< \omega_{0}, &\text{Underdamped} \\
  \omega_c &= \sqrt{\mu^{2} - \omega_{0}^{2}}, & \mu &> \omega_{0}, &\text{Overdamped} \\
  \omega_c &= 0,                               & \mu &= \omega_{0}, &\text{Critically damped}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I recommend the OP to read the `amsmath` manual on a rainy afternoon!

Comment: Needed to say, if you change `&\text{...}` into `&&\text{...}` (doubling the last et-signs), you'll get the helper text left-aligned, should anyone prefer it.