# writing text next to equations in array

Tags: equations, arrays

I am trying to reproduce the attached picture: But I can't in any way figure out what the correct way to write text next to an equation is.

Is there a package for this?

[image]

Comment: This question is surely solved on the site, but I can't find it now. The thing you look for is `align` in the manual of `amsmath`. In the above example, the first line would be something like `\frac{du}{dz} &= 0 & \text{(continuity)}`, all the lines following the same scheme, encapsuled in `\begin{align}...\end{align}` and seperated by ```\\```.

Comment: And you would most likely use the `subequations` environment to have equations numbered the way you display them.

Comment: @tohecz `&&\text{(continuity)}`

Comment: Perhaps the following: [To have nice tabbed text next to equations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147592/5764)

Comment: @Werner That seems to be the one. Let's wait if BillyJean is satisfied with your answer there :)

Comment: @tohecz thanks for the help, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a slighly different alignment for the text, using the `alignat` environment:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}%
    \usepackage[ textwidth = 15cm, nomarginpar]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage[thin,thinp,thinc]{esdiff}

    \begin{document}

        \begin{subequations}
            \begin{alignat}{2}
                \diffp{u}{z} + \frac{1}{r}\diffp{\hphantom{r}}{r}(rv) & = 0 & \qquad & \text{(continuity)}\\%
                \rho\left(u\diffp{u}{z} + v\diffp{u}{r}\right) & = -\diffp{p}{z} + \mu\left[\diffp[2]{u}{z} + \frac{1}{r}\diffp{\hphantom{r}}{r}\left(r\diffp{u}{r}\right)\right] & &\text{($ z $ momentum)}\\%
                \rho\left(u\diffp{v}{z} + v\diffp{v}{r}\right) & = -\diffp{p}{z} + \mu\left[\diffp[2]{v}{z} + \frac{1}{r}\diffp{\hphantom{r}}{r}\left(r\diffp{v}{r}\right)\right] & &\text{($ z $ momentum)}
            \end{alignat}
        \end{subequations}

    \end{document
```

[image]